# "По крайней мере"

Tags: пунктуация

Выделяется ли запятыми оборот "по крайней мере"? По идее, он вводный, но мне попадались предложения, где он запятыми не выделялся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Многие из вводных слов и сочетаний слов (в их числе и **по крайней мере**) могут быть омонимичны членам предложения или союзам. Такие различия (они отражаются на пунктуации) проявляются в контексте. Например, *Дай мне удостовериться, **по крайней мере**, что теперь хорошо тебе (Леон.); В Москве последний счастливый день Мити был  девятого марта. Так, **по крайней мере**, казалось ему (Бун.). — Изредка до земли прорезались бледные зигзаги молнии. Ясно было, что на нынешний день разойдется у нас **по крайней мере*** (Л. Т.).
Об этом можно прочитать, например, в Правилах русской орфографии и пунктуации под ред. Лопатина (§ 93-96).